# Spring Data Redis InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am currently trying my hands on Spring Data Redis in order to getting and putting my data to a redis repository. However, upon running my apps using `mvn spring-boot:run`, It always returns error with below message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project networkprofile-bs-redis-poc: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Invalid bean definition with name 'metadataRepository' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.redis.repository.support.RedisRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'metadataRepository': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound. -> [Help 1]
```

I have two repository interfaces in my code, `MetadataRepository` and `ProfileRepository`, and for some reason the error keeps going back and forth between those two, with the same `InvocationTargetException`.

**MetadataRepository**

```
package xxx.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import xxx.model.redis.Metadata;

public interface MetadataRepository extends CrudRepository<Metadata, String> {}
```

**ProfileRepository**

```
package xxx.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import xxx.model.redis.Profile;

public interface ProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<Profile, String> {
    Profile findByMsisdnAndProfile(String msisdn, String profile);
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
...

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

...

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    
    ...    

    <axiom.version>1.2.21</axiom.version>
    <springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>
    
    ...
    
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>${axiom.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${axiom.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have set some Redis Configuration as below:

```
package xxx.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${xxx.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;
    
    @Value("${xxx.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;
    
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(){
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure on what causes this because this is different from the similar problem that throws `BeanDefinitionOverrideException`.

---

My goal is that so my apps can run without problems, so I need to pinpoint the cause of this. Perhaps there is something I've done incorrectly?

---

### Update

I found out that `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` and `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` is causing the conflict in my build, resulting in `InvocationTargetException`. Upon excluding the JDBC dependencies, the `InvocationTargetException` disappears.
However, doing so will break my other modules which requires JDBC connection. So I would need both the JDBC and Redis dependencies in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was stuck with a similar problem for almost two days, but finally figured it out. The thing is, when multiple Spring Data modules are used in a project, the Spring framework enters into strict repository configuration mode and uses different detection mechanisms underneath, to identify which repository belongs to which persistence technology (explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-multiple-data-modules#datastore-detection)).

In your case, two Spring Data modules i.e. spring-data-jdbc and spring-data-redis are used. So, The ProfileRepository and MetadataRepository, defined in your project, could be used as repository both for spring-data-jdbc and spring-data-redis. An approach to solve this problem is to use [module specific annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-multiple-data-modules#2-using-module-specific-annotations-on-the-domain-objects). For example, to define ProfileRepository as a Repository related to Redis, you must define your Profile class as :

```
@RedisHash("Profile")
public class Profile implements Serializable {
// fields and getters/setters as usual
}
```

OR, if you want to define ProfileRepository as a Repository related to JDBC, you must define your Profile class as :

```
@Table("Profile")
public class Profile implements Serializable {
// fields and getters/setters as usual
}
```

Comment: Apparently the `CrudRepository` interfaces implemented by the repository in my project clashed between `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` and `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`. In your explanation, it looks like I have to make a separate model classes for Redis and JDBC; while in reality, the JDBC actually required by one of my dependencies, so I would not need to make a JDBC data model. Is there a way to disregard the `CrudRepository` for the `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` since I only need the one in `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`?

Comment: To disregard the CrudRepository for spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc, simply use @RedisHash in your entity (domain class), it should solve the problem. I had exactly same situation in my project and doing so solved the problem.
P.S. I have slightly improved my answer. If it solved the problem, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer:)