# Spring Data CrudRepository's save throws InvocationTargetException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

I have spent the whole weekend trying to debug this piece of code. I have a Spring RestController :

```
import com.tsakirogf.schedu.model.ContactMean;
import com.tsakirogf.schedu.model.DefaultContactMean;
import com.tsakirogf.schedu.model.human.Business;
import com.tsakirogf.schedu.services.BusinessService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/business/")
public class BusinessController
{
    @Autowired
    BusinessService businessService;

    @GetMapping(value = "businesss")
    Iterable<Business> list()
    {
        Iterable<Business> retVal = businessService.findAll();
        return retVal;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "business", method = RequestMethod.POST,  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Business create(@RequestBody Business business)
    {
        CollectionOfContactMethods collectionOfContact = business.getContact();
        collectionOfContact.setBusiness(business);
        Set<ContactMean> contactMeanSet = collectionOfContact.getContactMeans();
        DefaultContactMean defaultContactMeanSet = collectionOfContact.getDefaultContactMean();
        defaultContactMeanSet.getCollectionOfContactMethodsDefault().setId(collectionOfContact.getId());
        for (ContactMean element : contactMeanSet)
        {
            element.setCollectionOfContactMethods(collectionOfContact);
        }
        collectionOfContact.setDefaultContactMean(defaultContactMeanSet);
        business.setContact(collectionOfContact);

        Business retval = businessService.save(business);
        return retval;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "business/{id}",  method = RequestMethod.GET )
    Optional<Business> get(@PathVariable Long id)
    {
        return businessService.findById(id);
    }
}
```

And the service :

```
public interface BusinessService extends CrudRepository<Business, Long>
{
}
```

This is the model :

```
@Table(name = "business")
public class Business
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "business_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @Embedded
    @JsonProperty("address")
    private Address address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "business",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonProperty("operatives")
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<Professional> operatives;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "business",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        optional = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JsonProperty("contact_numbers")
    private CollectionOfContactMethods contact;

    public Business()
    {
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

When I send a POST request like this :

[image: Postman]

Where I got the following

> {
> "timestamp": "2021-11-01T08:59:06.343+00:00",
> "status": 500,
> "error": "Internal Server Error",
> "path": "/api/v1/business/business"
> }

I debug and I am getting *InvocationTargetException* as seen below
This is the controller, right before save() which seems to throw :
[image: Controller state before catch]

And here is the catch :
[image]

I found [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-multiple-data-modules#datastore-detection) posted in a [similar event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950633/spring-data-redis-invocationtargetexception) in StackOverflow but I don't think that's what is happening in this case since I have only H2 database for now.
This is application.properties file :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you include stackstrace?

Comment: will be my pleasure

Comment: You have an `id` field which has no generator assigned to it. So you need to either change that or manually assign an `id` to the object before saving.

Comment: Jesus. How did I miss that? @M.Deinum that was it (@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)), Please feel free to create an answer and get the point. You well deserve it. Also, I am going to keep this question since this exception seems little missleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your last screenshot you see a message indicating that there is an `id` field that has no value.

In your entity you have the following declaration of your `id` field:

```java
@Id
@Column(name = "business_id", nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

Which indicates to hibernate that it shouldn't generate a key or that there is no database assigned one. Which means you will manually need to set the value for `id`. If you don't you will run into this exception.

Now I assume that this was a mistake and that you actually wanted to have a sequence or auto-incremented `id` field. For this add the `@GeneratedValue` annotation to add this behavior.

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE))
@Column(name = "business_id", nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

This will instruct hibernate to use a sequence to generate the `id` upon inserting the entity. If your database supports `identity` columns you might want to use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` instead of `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`.